# post method dont send data with FormRequest laravel9

Tags: php, laravel, forms, backend, laravel-artisan

profile controller :

```
 public function store(ProfileRequest $request)
   
    {     dd($ProfileRequest);
        $formFields= $request->validated() ;
       
        $formFields['option'] = $request->input('option');
        $formFields['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        
        $profile=Profile::create($formFields);
        return  redirect()->route('login')->with('success','profil ajouté avec succes !');
    
    }
```

FormRequest :

```
class ProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|between:5,10',   //|max:10    
            'email' => 'required | email | unique:profiles',
            'password' =>'required |min:8|confirmed', 
            'bio' =>'required',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,svg,jpeg|max:10500',
        ];
    }
}
```

i use resource method for routes when i try to submit the Form noting returned :

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('Profiles.store')}}">
        @csrf
      /.. inputs here../
    </form>
```

when i trye to change

```
public function store(ProfileRequest $request)
to 
function store(Request $request)
```

i reserve data but when i still using   the first noting return

Comment: Try debugging `dd($request);`.

Comment: Or try with  `dd($request->all())`

Comment: So when you read a function like `store(ProfileRequest $request)` what do you understand when you see the param as `ProfileRequest $request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dd($request->all());` insted of `dd($ProfileRequest);` for debugging.

I see you are upload image so add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag
Like this `<form method="POST" action="{{route('Profiles.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`